# How to use Conditional "Else IF" Statement in Microsoft Word Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, conditional-statements

I encountered the following code on a word document, see below image, the "IF statement" in the image sets the criteria if the field {MergeField M_CX...} =  "JGray" then it displays JGray's signature (image) on the front-end of the document.

the problem I am having is, I cannot figure out how to add a possibility "Else IF" statement where if the field is Not equal to "JGray", I would want to display another image, basically my own signature image. How to I write that code?

Current code:

```
    {IF {MERGEFIELD M_CXdotSIGNATUREdotJGRAY
 }="JGRAY" ("image") \*
MERGEFORMAT }
```

The current code in image format :

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: I just added code in writing, but the main reason I added screenshot is because there is an image added into the code.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. If it's "image" information, then an image is fine. But for text information, it should all be here as text to help people looking at your post understand it better, including copying/pasting into their own applications in order to test it.